# node.js safety of asynchronous array

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var docs = [];

server.on('add', function(item){
    docs.push(item);
});

setInterval(function(){
    save(docs);
}, 3000);

var save = function(array) {
    var items = array.slice(0); // copy array
    array.length = 0; // clear array

    mongodb.insert(items, function(){
        // ...
    });
};
```

I would like to save documents to RAM and next save to mongodb. Is this code safe?

Mongodb server is in EU, application server is in US. It is added 2-3k items per sec to the base. I would like to decrease quantity of connections. My question: It is possible that during save to the base the variable will be modificate (in 'add')

Comment: Safe in what regard? Btw, why wouldn't you just insert them directly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This depends on weather `mongodb.insert(docs);` performs the operation for all elements in one go. If it triggers a callback after each inserted element, then your code is not safe (because your array will be cleared after the first inserted element).

If however the operation is synchronous for all elements then your code should be safe.

Comment: No. The array was never *cleared*, it was replaced with an empty array.

Comment: @Sannin, yea your latest version of the code should be fine

Comment: @Bergi: array.length = 0; better? :) Thanks!

Comment: @Sannin: I was referring to mihai's answer, which is wrong. You initial version with `items = [];` was totally fine. Only if you did use `items.length = 0` you would get the problems that mihai describes in his answer.